# PHP error is visible in production in shared hosting

Tags: php

I am getting the below error in one of the file in Production, where the function is  defined twice. I tried to recreate the issue, getting in a different file.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare foo() (previously declared in
>   /home/content/45/8989001/html/test/test.php:5) in
>   /home/content/45/8989001/html/test/test.php on line 10

To suppress this error, its advised to make an entry to `php.ini` file, but I don't have access to it as its shared hosting.

Alternatively, its suggested to make an entry to existing php file inside the `<?php ?>` tags. I did the below change.

```
error_reporting(0); // This is not working, still error is displayed
error_reporting(E_NONE); // This is not working, still error is displayed
ini_set('display_errors', 0); // This is not working, still error is displayed
```

My complete code,

```
<?php
function foo() {
    return "foo";
}
function foo() {
    return "foo";
}

// error_reporting(0); // This is not working, still error is displayed
// error_reporting(E_NONE); // This is not working, still error is displayed
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 0 ); // This is not working, still error is displayed

echo "hello";

?>
```

**Problem:** How to suppress this error in Production, instead log to some file. or at-least suppress the error?

*Note: The error is fixed in prod, but how to suppress it to avoid user seeing error in some other file next time*

**Update1:**

After the below change too, the error is the same.

```
<?php
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 0 );

function foo() {
    return "foo";
}
function foo() {
    return "foo";
}

// error_reporting(0); // This is not working, still error is displayed
// error_reporting(E_NONE); // This is not working, still error is displayed
// ini_set ( 'display_errors', 0 ); // This is not working, still error is displayed

echo "hello";

?>
```

**Update2:**

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function( "fatal_handler" );
function fatal_handler() {
    echo "inside fatal_handler";
    $errfile = "test";
    $errstr  = "shutdown this test";
    $errno   = E_CORE_ERROR;
    $errline = 0;

    $error = error_get_last();

    echo $error;

    if( $error !== NULL) {
        $errno   = $error["type"];
        $errfile = $error["file"];
        $errline = $error["line"];
        $errstr  = $error["message"];

        $newline = "\r\n";
        define ( 'senderName', 'Error' );
        define ( 'senderEmail', 'admin@abc.com' );
        $headers = "From: " . senderName . " <" . senderEmail . "\r\n";

        $subject_admin = 'Error-Fix it';
        $body_admin = "Dear Admin, $newline$newline An error occured  $newline" . "error number : " . $errno . $newline . " error file : $errfile" . $newline . "error line :" . $errline . $newline . "error string : $errstr" . $newline;
        $body_footer = " **** This is an an auto-generated mail. kindly do not reply to this mail. Thank You. ****" . $newline . $newline;
        $body_admin = $body_admin . $newline . $newline . $newline . $body_footer;
        $to_admin1 = 'mymail@gmail.com';
        mail ( $to_admin1, $subject_admin, $body_admin, $headers );
        //error_mail(format_error( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline));
    }
}

function foo() {
    return "foo";
}
function foo() {
    return "foo";
}

// error_reporting(0); // This is not working, still error is displayed
// error_reporting(E_NONE); // This is not working, still error is displayed
// ini_set ( 'display_errors', 0 ); // This is not working, still error is displayed

echo "hello";
?>
```

**update 3**

Still getting same error

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function ( "fatal_handler" );
function fatal_handler() {
    echo 'YAY IT WORKED';
}
function foo() {
    return "foo";
}
function foo() {
    return "foo";
}

// error_reporting(0); // This is not working, still error is displayed
// error_reporting(E_NONE); // This is not working, still error is displayed
// ini_set ( 'display_errors', 0 ); // This is not working, still error is displayed

echo "hello";
?>
```

**Update4**

```
<?php 
//error_reporting(0);

function fatalErrorHandler() {
    echo 'YAY IT WORKED';
}

# Registering shutdown function
register_shutdown_function('fatalErrorHandler');

// let force a Fatal error -- function does not exist
functiontest();

echo "hello";

?>
<!-- 
output:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function functiontest() in ...test2.php on line 12
YAY IT WORKED -->

<?php 
error_reporting(0); 

function fatalErrorHandler() {
    echo 'YAY IT WORKED';
}

# Registering shutdown function
register_shutdown_function('fatalErrorHandler');

// let force a Fatal error -- function does not exist
functiontest();

echo "hello";

?>

<!-- output:

YAY IT WORKED -->
```

Final update:

This resolved my intermediate question
[register_shutdown_function is not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708952/register-shutdown-function-is-not-getting-called/30709038#30709038)

Comment: Put the ini_set before any other statement... To clarify: If you want to suppress it, you need to explain to the processor _before_ doing anything...

Comment: And what about to fix error instead of hiding error message?

Comment: @panther Although you're right, the question is about how to suppress errors on production... ;)

Comment: Are you on a shared server? And do you have access to the php.ini?

Comment: @Raphioly-San: I read question, but it's bad question. Nothing else.

Comment: @panther : I fixed the error in production, but I don't want users to see if something happens wrong in some other file next time

Comment: @Raphioly-San . I followed ur comment, still error is displayed

Comment: @Hanoncs yes godaddy, I don't have access

Comment: @spiderman Did you really? Did you put the directives BEFORE the functions?

Comment: Don't suppress errors, fix errors

Comment: @MarkBaker even in professional evironments, errors may occur... But the last thing you want is the audience to witness it... So his question is good... But if it's an obvious flaw in your code, you should definitely fix it first... ;)

Comment: @Raphioly-San - Please see the update I added editing my OP. Yes I did

Comment: @spiderman [See this on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) it does not suppress fatal errors... Set the error_reporting() directive just after the opening tag as well... [See this page for error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Guys..  people down voted my question but failed to explain between parsing error and execution error. Here this one I posted separately explains it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708952/register-shutdown-function-is-not-getting-called/30709038#30709038

Comment: Thanks to all those who offered a helping hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would call my host and ask them to make the changes to my phpini. They may have special things setup.

Now you should never just hide errors. You send yourself an email and fix right away. The error you are trying to surpress is fatal and the script will no longer run, so hiding it only results in a blank page, the user stkill cannot continue.

It is a fatal error and you cannot recover from it. The way to hide fatal error properly in my opinion is to create your own error handler function.

And you would use something like this to catch the fatal errors.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

The function needs to be on every page in order to catth the error. I have a error.php that I require in my db class, which is on every page.

```
//This function gets called every time your script shutsdown
register_shutdown_function( "fatal_handler" );

function fatal_handler() {
  $errfile = "unknown file";
  $errstr  = "shutdown";
  $errno   = E_CORE_ERROR;
  $errline = 0;

  $error = error_get_last();

  if( $error !== NULL) {
    $errno   = $error["type"];
    $errfile = $error["file"];
    $errline = $error["line"];
    $errstr  = $error["message"];

    //send error email
    error_mail(format_error( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline));
  }
}
```

UPDATE

**OP said the function is not being called. **

***The above should work.***

Here is basically what I use in production, it should tottally work.

ON_SCREEN_ERRORS and SEND_ERROR_EMAIL are my own config constants for development.

```
//Set error handler function (See function below)
set_error_handler("StandardErrorHandler");

/**
 * Will take an error string and if ON_SCREEN_SQL_ERRORS  is set to on, it will display the error on the screen with the SQL in a readable format and
 * if SEND_SQL_ERROR_EMAILS is set to on, it will dendthe error email with the SQL in a readable format.
 * 
 *  PHP will pass these parameters automatically on error.
 *
 * @param string $errno The error type code.
 * @param string $errstr The error string.
 * @param string $errfile The file that the error occured in.
 * @param string $errline The line number that the error occured.
 */

function StandardErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    $Err = $errstr.'<br />'.GetErrorType($errno).'on line '.$errline.' in '.$errfile.'<br />';
    if (ON_SCREEN_ERRORS===TRUE)
    {
        err($Err);
    }
    if ($errno =='256' and SEND_ERROR_EMAILS === TRUE)
    {
        $Path = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        // Custom error function           
        gfErrEmail($Err, $Path, 'SQL Error');
    }
}


//Set the Fatal Error Handler function (See function below)
register_shutdown_function("FatalErrorHandler");

/**
 * This function gets called on script shutdown, it will check if the last error is a fatal error. You cannot catch fatal errors,
 * but using this function we will be notified about it and be able to fix it.
 * If error is fatal, and if ON_SCREEN_FATAL_ERRORS is set to ON, this function will display the fatal error on the screen.
 * If error is fatal, and if SEND_FATAL_ERROR_EMAILS is set to ON, this function will send error email.
 *
 */

function FatalErrorHandler() {

    $error = error_get_last();
    if($error !== NULL) {
         //check if error is of fatal, compliler or other non recoverable error types
        if ($error["type"] =='1' || $error["type"] =='4' || $error["type"] =='16' || $error["type"] =='64' || $error["type"] =='4096')
        {
            $errno  = GetErrorType($error["type"]);
            $errfile = $error["file"];
            $errline = $error["line"];
            $errstr  = $error["message"];
            $Err = '<strong>'.$errno.'<br/></strong>'.$errstr.'<br />'.$errno.' on line '.$errline.' in '.$errfile.'<br />';
            if (ON_SCREEN_ERRORS===TRUE)
            {
                err($Err);
            }
            if (SEND_ERROR_EMAILS === TRUE)
            {
                $Path = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                
                //Custom function
                gfErrEmail($Err, $Path, $errno);
            }
        }
    }
}



/**
 * This function receives the error code and returns the specified string. 
 * The return strings are what the error message will display.
 *
 * @return string The error title
 */
function GetErrorType($Type)
{
    switch($Type) 
    { 
        case 1:
            // 'E_ERROR'; 
            return 'Fatal Error ';
        case 2:
            // 'E_WARNING'; 
            return 'Warning ';
        case 4:
            // 'E_PARSE'; 
            return 'Compile Time Parse Error ';
        case 8:
            // 'E_NOTICE'; 
            return 'Notice ';
        case 16:
            // 'E_CORE_ERROR'; 
            return 'Fatal Start up Error ';
        case 32:
            // 'E_CORE_WARNING'; 
            return 'Start Up Warning ';
        case 64:
            //'E_COMPILE_ERROR'; 
            return 'Fatal Compile Time Error ';
        case 128:
            // 'E_COMPILE_WARNING'; 
            return 'Compile Time Warning ';
        case 256 :
            // 'E_USER_ERROR' - USED FOR SQL ERRORS - DO NOT USE THIS ERROR CODE to TRIGGER_ERROR()
            return 'SQL Error ';
        case 512:  
            // 'E_USER_WARNING'; 
            return  'Warning - Thrown using trigger_error() ';
        case 1024:  
            // 'E_USER_NOTICE'; 
            return  'Notice - Thrown using trigger_error() ';
        case 2048: 
            // 'E_STRICT'; 
            return 'Strict Error (PHP suggest changes to your code which will ensure the best interoperability and forward compatibility of your code.) ';
        case 4096: 
            // 'E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR'; 
            return 'Catchable Fatal Error (This error can be caught, use a Try Catch) ';
        case 8192: 
            // 'E_DEPRECATED'; 
            return 'Warns you of depreciated code that will not work in future versions of PHP. ';
        case 16384: 
            // 'E_USER_DEPRECATED'; 
            return  'Programmer Triggered Error - Thrown using trigger_error() ';
    } 
    return "Error Type Undefined "; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Appreciate your suggestion, This must be the approach. I added this code after all my logic , ie after `echo "hello";` in my use-case here. But I am not getting any email, and I tried putting this line and it's not displaying that as well `function fatal_handler() { echo "inside fatal_handler";`

Comment: The email function is not complete. You will need to make your own email functions and also the format_error function. That is for example of what to do.

Comment: Please check the check mark if you feel I have answered your question.

Comment: I understand, I have email function in my code that works. I have updated my question to show you what I am doing after your proposed change. I will upvote for sure for the approach, but I still have the error though

Comment: Ok. You say: Note: The error is fixed in prod, but how to suppress it to avoid user seeing error in some other file next time....what does that mean?? What is wrong?

Comment: I meant to say, that I fixed the error in production this time. But I don't know if there are errors anywhere else. So next time someone tries some other functionality, I don't want them to see the error, and I wanted to suppress the display. But your approach of sending email is also fine, but your method is not getting called :(

Comment: I added to my answer how to catch the error in every page on your site. What do you mean it is not getting called?

Comment: Please see my update 2. I am doing exactly as you are suggesting. If the callback function was called, then the email should have been sent, or the `echo' should have been worked

Comment: Try this:...... register_shutdown_function( "fatal_handler" );

function fatal_handler() { echo 'YAY IT WORKED';}

Comment: You do not have the email correct try my above comment.

Comment: Sorry man, I gave you my production code, read the link I sent you. I can't spend anymore time on this.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thank you so much I will accept as answer. I have posted a last update as Update4, which is working, but when I define a function twice as in my real use-case, it is not working. Probably something really going on.

Comment: cool man no prob. Also check your php error logs for the true error

Comment: I have posted that as a different question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708952/register-shutdown-function-is-not-getting-called

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708952/register-shutdown-function-is-not-getting-called/30709038#30709038 this resolved it