# register_shutdown_function is not getting called

Tags: php

This is a snippet from my original code I am testing to handle error.

The FIRST approach is calling the `fatalErrorHandler()`, but the SECOND approach is not calling the `fatalErrorHandler()`. What could be the reason?

**FIRST**

```
<?php 
//error_reporting(0);

function fatalErrorHandler() {
    echo 'YAY IT WORKED';
}

# Registering shutdown function
register_shutdown_function('fatalErrorHandler');

// let force a Fatal error -- function does not exist
functiontest();

echo "hello";

?>
```

> **output:**
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function functiontest() in ...test2.php
>   on line 12 YAY IT WORKED

**SECOND**

```
 <?php 
    //error_reporting(0);

    function fatalErrorHandler() {
        echo 'YAY IT WORKED';
    }

    # Registering shutdown function
    register_shutdown_function('fatalErrorHandler');

    // let force a Fatal error -- function does not exist
    functiontest();

    function foo () {

    }

    function foo() {

    }

    echo "hello";

    ?>
```

**Output:**

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare foo() (previously declared in
>   ...test/test2.php:16) in ../test2.php on line 20

**fatalErrorHandler is not getting called in this scenario. why?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP you can use a function before you define it. I think this means that the interpreter must parse all functions before it starts execution. So `register_shutdown_function` is not yet called when this error is detected.

You could test this by moving the duplicate function definition into a separate file and including it with `include` or `require`.

Comment: +1. The second error is thrown while parsing the file, not while executing it. The first error is not detected while parsing because of the reasons Halcyon wrote.

Comment: Which is why it is considered best to keep any fatal error handlers in a separate file that you modify as little as possible and include as the very first thing :)

Comment: @halcyon and @ bmurauer thank you for mentioning the cause.. Error is thrown at parse time not execution. That resolves my question. But how do I fix this error in real time. Meaning, I got this error when I included two different files and both of them had defined the same function. Or may be in my real time case, your explanation would work as it is parsed correctly.. I will check and update. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I think it's about compiling order. See the condition.

Take a look at this example:

```
// The shutdown function won't be called
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    echo "I'm in!";
});
function test(){}
function test(){}
```

And now at this example:

```
// The shutdown function will be called
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    echo "I'm in!";
});
function test(){}
if(1 === 1)
{
    function test(){}
}
```